# error in hibernate java (StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Error when run main methode in line `StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();`

```java
package hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class StoreData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();

        SessionFactory factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setId(1);
        e1.setFirstName("Gaurav");
        e1.setLastName("Chawla");

        session.save(e1);
        t.commit();
        System.out.println("successfully saved");
        factory.close();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="connection.username">ceid</property>
        <property name="connection.password">2361368</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

employee.hbm.xml

and another before compile in line table and column in class and property tag

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="hibernate">
    <class name="hibernate.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="firstName" column="firstname" type="string"></property>
        <property name="lastName" column="lastname" type="string"></property>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee.java

```java
package hibernate;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String firstName, lastName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

My database is Oracle 11.2 XE and table is

```sql
  CREATE TABLE "CEID"."EMPLOYEE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   )
```

This is an example from
https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-create-hibernate-application-in-eclipse-ide

Error log in this example

```
Sep 11, 2021 6:02:40 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
Sep 11, 2021 6:02:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
    at hibernate.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:14)
```

Comment: Don't just say "there is an error". Error messages contain important information about what's wrong. What is the exact error message?

Comment: thank you for your comment

I add error log at end of the question

Comment: The error message tells you that Hibernate cannot find the file `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Make sure you put that file in the right location.

Comment: maybe try to avoid it by using `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` in `Session session` opening ?

Comment: thank you 
location of hibernate.cfg.xml is correct
I think this problem was happen when library incorrect